How can I write a regular expression to find all matches in a text separated by either 2 spaces or a line break?
I'm having some difficulty finding a pattern which finds all of these matches, as I want each match to be able to have any character (including single space characters).

The only delimiters should be exactly 2 space characters, or a line break

See https://regex101.com/r/ra2Zil/1
